# Run custom code on login

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication

I’ve used the asp.net login control on my sharepoint custom master page. All works well and I can login to my site without problems.

However I’d like to run some code once the user has logged, or alternatively perform a redirect based on the user’s role.

Has anyone does this type of thing before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Login control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login) has an event LoggedIn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx). Just subscribe to it and place your code in the handler. I haven't worked with sharepoint, I'm talking from an ASP.NET viewpoint here.

Comment: doh! think i made that more difficult than it need to be, thanks for you help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can test roles programmatically through `User.IsInRole`

EDIT: on redirect from the ASP.NET login control, check for the forms authenication token and run your custom code if the token is present.