# ADO.Net Best way to run a procedure once after user authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that has to be run once when a user logs into my asp.net website. 
The closest event that i could find is the LoggedIn event on my login control, however i cannot use this as it is not able to find the UserId of the currently logged in user yet.

So, what is the best way to run a procedure once after a user is authenticated?

Comment: There should also be an OnAuthenticate event.

Comment: There is no OnAuthenticate event on the asp.net login control sadly.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002245/global-onloggedin-event-in-asp-net>

Comment: How exactly can i use the Session_start from global.asax to run my procedure? I cannot call it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a page refresh after login then run a function on page load looking for "if userid=not null run stored procedure".

Comment: Good idea, but i cannot use this. My Procedure writes a new record to the database everytime. if i set userid=not null it will never run.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the user yourself in onLoggedIn

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(LoginControlName.UserName);
// then do stuff with the user.
```